# How to rectify the unknown stage section error in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to the AWS and DEVOPS part, i developed one pipeline which is cloning and testing the project which i have pasted in Git section ,i am getting an error after  building the job

This is my error after building
[image: This is my error]
`pipeline script`

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('clone repository and clean project') { 
            steps {
                sh "rm -rf ADDRESS_BOOK"
                sh "git clone https://github.com/saitarun135/ADDRESS_BOOK"
                // sh "mvn clean -f ADDRESS_BOOK"
            }
            stage('Test'){
                steps{
                    sh "mvn test -f ADDRESS_BOOK"
                }
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins [declarative pipeline syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) is quite strict, and should follow a specific directive patterns, one of which is that `stage` directive must reside directly under the `stages` directive and not under another `stage`.
In your case it will look like:

```
pipeline {
   agent any 
   stages {
       stage('clone repository and clean project') { 
           steps {
               sh "rm -rf ADDRESS_BOOK"
               sh "git clone https://github.com/saitarun135/ADDRESS_BOOK"
               // sh "mvn clean -f ADDRESS_BOOK"
           }
        }
        stage('Test'){
            steps{
               sh "mvn test -f ADDRESS_BOOK"
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

If you want to have nested stages inside a parent `stage` it can be done but the parent stage cannot have a `steps` directive of its own. something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('clone repository and clean project') {
            steps {
                sh "rm -rf ADDRESS_BOOK"
                sh "git clone https://github.com/saitarun135/ADDRESS_BOOK"
            }
        }
        stage('Run Tests '){
            stages {
                stage('Test 1') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Run test 1...'
                    }
                }
                stage('Test 2') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Run test 2...'
                    }
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```